# Cloudflare php cURL get returns '1'

Tags: php, curl, get, cloudflare

I've noticed a wierd behavior of php curl GET query to Cloudflare API https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones

When using Postman — everything is okay and it show correct response

[image: correct answer by Postman]

But when trying to get via PHP it returns '1' for some reason. Here is my code and logs:
[image: php curl code]
[image: logs]

Also tried to pass in body, but it didn't work too
[image]

Please, help me to figure out the problem and fix it. Thanks!
p.s. i've also tried to pass urlencoded variable, but this also has no effect

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @mario but I've already added all needed code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in logs — i've just forgot to add second true parameter to print_r so it'll return the output